# Installing React-native calendars breaks installation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm a bit puzzled why two different npm installs for a react-native calendar are breaking the solution. I am running react-native through expo, and it runs fine before installing the calendar.

But after installing either 
     `react-native-general-calendars`
 or 
     `react-native-calendars` 
I get this error in the console after running 
     `expo start`:

```
> [17:30:29] Starting project at --location--
[17:30:33] Error: React native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.
[17:30:33] Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.
[17:30:33] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I run npm install and get the following error:

```
> [17:33:34] Starting project at --location--
[17:33:40] --location--\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\server\checkNodeVersion.js:43
[17:33:40]     );
[17:33:40]     ^
[17:33:40] SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
[17:33:40]     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
[17:33:40]     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
[17:33:40]     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
[17:33:40]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
[17:33:40]     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
[17:33:40]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
[17:33:40]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
[17:33:40]     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
[17:33:40]     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
[17:33:40]     at Object.<anonymous> (--location--\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\cli.js:17:1)
[17:33:40] Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
[17:33:40] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Here is my package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "my-new-project",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^29.0.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-general-calendars": "^1.7.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "^29.0.0"
  }
}
```

When I uninstall the calendar I still get the error now. Not sure how to get expo to stop throwing the error. Anyone know how to fix this?